# Textures in OpenGL turn white over time

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine, lwjgl

I have noticed that If I specify all of my textures as static such as:

```
public static Texture backgroundTexture = null;
public static Texture woodTexture = null;
public static Texture titleTexture = null;
public static Texture buttonStart = null;
public static Texture buttonStartPressed = null;
public static void initTextures(){
    try{
          backgroundTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/background.png"));
          woodTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/wood.png"));
          titleTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/titleTex.png"));
          buttonStart = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/startReady.png"));;
          buttonStartPressed = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/startPressed.png"));;
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.toString());}
```

That my textures work perfectly fine, But I would imagine, that as I amass more textures I would start raping my computers RAM.
So I decided that I should use this to dynamically load the textures as I need them:

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String location){
    Texture tex = null;
    try{
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/"+location+".png"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Failed loading Texture: "+location);
    }
    if(tex==null){
        System.err.println("We had a freaking null texture! it was called: "
                + location);
    }
    return tex;
}
```

But when I do this after a certain amount of time the entire texture becomes white(thats my default draw color). But the other ones that are static still work fine. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the texture object you are overwriting with loadTexture() is being garbage collected, and the previously allocated GPU resource that you had assisted to your geometry is discarded. If you are not binding the new resource provided by loadTexture() with glBindTexture() that could explain why the texture doesn't update.

Comment: How do I ensure that It doesn't get garbage collected while I need to use it?

Comment: You need to hold off on replacing its reference, or bind the new resource beforehand.

Comment: Well, If i keep using static references to a list of my textures will it hog up ram? or does it just use ram while its binded?

Comment: Any active textures will be taking up VRAM on the GPU. You need to delete them but from what I've seen it seems like you're not binding the new texture. Granted, I've only seen a small snippet of your code, so I don't see how you're using that call.

Comment: I'm using loadTexture("textureName").bind() everytime I draw the quad. So theoritically every render tick I'm loading a new texture object and binding it.

Comment: Every frame? That sounds problematic. Under the hood there are only so many textures that can be created at once, and the garbage collector can only work so quickly. Why don't you call loadTexture() only when the scene changes? Surely you can store five textures at once without issue. LWJGL should have tools to tell you how much gpu memory you have to work with.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll implement an ArrayList of Texture objects that Need to be currently used and only change them as screens update or textures need to be changed.